# Server Error on MailApp.sendEmail yet email still sends in Google spreadsheet script

Tags: google-apps-script

The following function give the error,

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
>   (line 144, file "Code")Dismiss

each time it runs.  The email is sent, and line 144 in the file is the line with MailApp.sendEmail({
Any idea what might need to be causing this error?

```
function sendEmails(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bookings");

  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 4);
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Templates");
  var emailAddressReplyTo = templateSheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var emailSubject = templateSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var emailHTMLTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("C3").getValue();

  // Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
  var objects = getRowsData(dataSheet);

  // For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
  // it to the appropriate person.
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
    var rowData = objects[i];
    rowData.rowNumber = i + 2;
    if (!rowData.action) { // if no state send booking confirmation

    var emailHTMLBody = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailHTMLTemplate, rowData);


    var emailSubjectText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailSubject, rowData);

    var emailText = processHTML(emailHTMLBody);

    var sendToEmailAddress = rowData.emailAddress;


 MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: sendToEmailAddress,
     replyTo: emailAddressReplyTo,
     subject: emailSubjectText,
     body: emailText,
     htmlBody: emailHTMLBody
   });

      }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the code was trying to send a second email for the first empty row in the spreadsheet.  When I changed the test to see if I needed to send an email to also test for an empty line, all worked well.  So

```
    if (!rowData.action) { // if no state send booking confirmation
```

became:

```
    if ((!rowData.action) && (rowData.countOfRegistrations > 0.9)) { // if no state AND there are 1 or more registrations send booking confirmation
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem in your script.

What is the objetive of the code bellow?

```
emailAddressReplyTo, htmlBody: emailHTMLBody});
```

Seems that you didn't copied and pasted it correct or maybe that's why your code is failing.

Comment: Sorry.  I fixed that.  It was part of a line from testing that was commented out.  It only partially deleted when I cleaned up my paste into the message to remove commented out code.

Comment: Please log the value of every variable used in MailApp.send and tell me the contents

Comment: Sorry for the dealyed response.  I am not getting emails when a response is made.

Comment: I changed email addresses, phone numbers, and names to dummy values. I logged each variable passed to MailApp.sendEmail in the same order in which they are passed. I also have to place as multiple comments due to length. I will break these as whole units if possible. The first part is the lines I added prior to SendMail.
Logger.log(sendToEmailAddress);
Logger.log(emailAddressReplyTo);
Logger.log(emailSubjectText);
Logger.log(emailText);
Logger.log(emailHTMLBody];

Following comments will contain the Log entries.

Comment: The rest is the Log Entry.  

[14-03-01 20:20:35:253 EST] kmail@gmail.com
[14-03-01 20:20:35:254 EST] bmail@me.com
[14-03-01 20:20:35:254 EST] Registration Canada 2014 Completed By K Sum

Comment: [14-03-01 20:20:35:254 EST] Hi K Sum,

Thanks for your Canada (Editor's note: Body too long to post)
Warm wishes,
C Nan
www.boxwood.org
111.222.3333 (CAN)
111.222.3333 (USA)

Click here to Edit your Registration

Your submitted details are:
Primary Contact Name: K Sum
Primary Contact Telephone Number: 444-555-6666
Primary Contact Email Address: kmail@gmail.com
Registration(s):
Adult Work Study Registration: K Sum

Total Registration(s) Cost in US Dollars: $
Registration Fees Break Down as:
Adult Registration Cost: $395
Billet Cost: $250
Shuttle Cost: $50

Comment: [14-03-01 20:20:35:255 EST] Hi,
<br/>
<p>(Editor: Body too long to post)</p>
<p>Warm wishes,<br/>
C Nan<br/>
<a href="http://www.box.org">www.box.org</a><br/>
1.2.3 (CAN)<br/>
1.2.3 (USA)<br/>
</p>
<p><b><a href=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1N8l-rlHL_XtcACg/viewform?edit=CzAA>Click here to Edit</a></b></p>
</p>
<h2>Details:</h2>
<p><b>Contact:</b> K Sum<br/>
<b>Telephone:</b> 444-555-6666<br/>
<b>Email:</b> kmail@gmail.com</p>
<h3>Registration(s):</h3>
<p>Adult: K Sum<br/>
<b>Total Cost:</b> $<br/>
<b>Registration Fees:</b><br/>
A Cost: $395<br/>
B Cost: $250<br/>
S Cost: $50<br/>

Comment: Oddly, the variables are listed multiple times even though I only ran the function once. This set seems to be missing information placed in variables via the fillInTemplateFromObject() calls as well as the variables :[14-03-01 20:20:35:486 EST] undefined
[14-03-01 20:20:35:486 EST] bmail@me.com
[14-03-01 20:20:35:487 EST] Registration to Boxwood Canada 2014 Completed By

Comment: [14-03-01 20:20:35:487 EST] Hi ,

Than (Editor's note: Body too long to post)  rg!
Warm wishes,
C Nan
www.box.org
1.2.3 (CAN)
1.2.3 (USA)

Click here to Edit your Registration

Your submitted details are:
Name: 
Telephone Number: 
Email Address: 
Registration(s):

Total Cost in : $
Registration Fees Break Down as:

Comment: [14-03-01 20:20:35:487 EST] Hi ,
<br/>
<p>Thanks for you age at <a href="http://www.box.org/canada_participant">www.box.org/canada_participant</a> where w dnburg!</p>
<p>Warm wishes,<br/>
C Nan<br/>
<a href="http://www.box.org">www.box.org</a><br/>
1.2.3 (CAN)<br/>
1.2.3 (USA)<br/>
</p>
<p><b><a href=>Click here to Edit your Registration</a></b></p>
</p>
<h2>Details are:</h2>
<p><b>Name:</b> <br/>
<b>Telephone Number:</b> <br/>
<b>Email Address:</b> </p>
<h3>Registration(s):</h3>
<p><br/>
<b>Total Cost in :</b> $<br/>
<b>Registration Fees Break Down as:</b><br/>

Comment: That is all the listing from the Logger calls.  I had to remove parts to make it fit in these comments. I removed parts that were straight text. I did change urls as well, especially the one to edit the form's entry. There is no call in the code to the sendEmails function and there is only one trigger to it in the current project. I do not believe it is running twice but could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I changed email addresses, phone numbers, and names to dummy values. I logged each variable passed to MailApp.sendEmail in the same order in which they are passed. The first part is the lines I added prior to SendMail.

```
Logger.log(sendToEmailAddress);
Logger.log(emailAddressReplyTo);
Logger.log(emailSubjectText);
Logger.log(emailText);
Logger.log(emailHTMLBody];
```

The following are the Log entries:

```
[14-03-01 20:20:35:253 EST] kmail@gmail.com 
[14-03-01 20:20:35:254 EST] bmail@me.com 
[14-03-01 20:20:35:254 EST] Registration Canada 2014 Completed By K Sum
[14-03-01 20:20:35:254 EST] Hi K Sum, Thanks for your Canada (Editor's note: Body too long to post) Warm wishes, C Nan www.boxwood.org 111.222.3333 (CAN) 111.222.3333 (USA) Click here to Edit your Registration Your submitted details are: Primary Contact Name: K Sum Primary Contact Telephone Number: 444-555-6666 Primary Contact Email Address: kmail@gmail.com Registration(s): Adult Work Study Registration: K Sum Total Registration(s) Cost in US Dollars: $ Registration Fees Break Down as: Adult Registration Cost: $395 Billet Cost: $250 Shuttle Cost: $50 – user284774 Mar 2 at 1:53   
[14-03-01 20:20:35:255 EST] Hi, <br/> <p>(Editor: Body too long to post)</p> <p>Warm wishes,<br/> C Nan<br/> <a href="box.org">www.box.org</a><br/>; 1.2.3 (CAN)<br/> 1.2.3 (USA)<br/> </p> <p><b><a href=docs.google.com/forms/d/1N8l-rlHL_XtcACg/… here to Edit</a></b></p> </p> <h2>Details:</h2> <p><b>Contact:</b> K Sum<br/> <b>Telephone:</b> 444-555-6666<br/> <b>Email:</b> kmail@gmail.com</p> <h3>Registration(s):</h3> <p>Adult: K Sum<br/> <b>Total Cost:</b> $<br/> <b>Registration Fees:</b><br/> A Cost: $395<br/> B Cost: $250<br/> S Cost: $50<br/>
```

Oddly, the variables are listed multiple times even though I only ran the function once. This set seems to be missing information placed in variables via the fillInTemplateFromObject() calls as well as the variables:

```
[14-03-01 20:20:35:486 EST] undefined 
[14-03-01 20:20:35:486 EST] bmail@me.com 
[14-03-01 20:20:35:487 EST] Registration to Boxwood Canada 2014 Completed By
[14-03-01 20:20:35:487 EST] Hi , Than (Editor's note: Body too long to post) rg! Warm wishes, C Nan www.box.org 1.2.3 (CAN) 1.2.3 (USA) Click here to Edit your Registration Your submitted details are: Name: Telephone Number: Email Address: Registration(s): Total Cost in : $ Registration Fees Break Down as: 
[14-03-01 20:20:35:487 EST] Hi , <br/> <p>Thanks for you age at <a href="box.org/canada_participant">www.box.org/…; where w dnburg!</p> <p>Warm wishes,<br/> C Nan<br/> <a href="box.org">www.box.org</a><br/>; 1.2.3 (CAN)<br/> 1.2.3 (USA)<br/> </p> <p><b><a href=>Click here to Edit your Registration</a></b></p> </p> <h2>Details are:</h2> <p><b>Name:</b> <br/> <b>Telephone Number:</b> <br/> <b>Email Address:</b> </p> <h3>Registration(s):</h3> <p><br/> <b>Total Cost in :</b> $<br/> <b>Registration Fees Break Down as:</b><br/>
```

That is all the listing from the Logger calls. I had to remove parts to make it fit in these comments. I removed parts that were straight text. I did change urls as well, especially the one to edit the form's entry. There is no call in the code to the sendEmails function and there is only one trigger to it in the current project. I do not believe it is running twice but could be wrong.